# Auto generate firebase tables from flutter model

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and just downloaded a sample project. In the project there are many models such as the one below.

**My question:**

Is it possible to auto generate these keys IN firebase without manually adding each key by hand:

[image]

**Flutter Model:**

```
 class CategoriesModel {
  String id;

  String name;

  String order;

  String photo;

  String title;

  CategoriesModel(
      {this.id = '',
      this.name = '',
      this.order = '',
      this.photo = '',
      this.title = ''});

  factory CategoriesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return CategoriesModel(
        id: parsedJson['id'] ?? '',
        name: parsedJson['name'] ?? '',
        order: parsedJson['order'] ?? '',
        photo: parsedJson['photo'] ?? '',
        title: parsedJson['title'] ?? '');
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': this.id,
      'name': this.name,
      'order': this.order,
      'photo': this.photo,
      'title': this.title
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is a schemaless database. There is nothing built into the API or the console to auto-generate data for your.

But you can of course fairly easily generate data through the API. I typically start with a file with some data to test with, and then either simply import that upon connecting, or generate random models from the JSON data by adding a `factory CategoriesModel.random` factory method.

Comment: Ahh that makes complete sense, thanks for clearing that up!